# Laravel Passport 401 following documentation

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0

I followed the documentation to install larval passport using larval 5.6. Currently when I hit any of my api routes with the api guard I will get an 401 http status on the request. I look threw hundreds or it seems like it discussions of this topic and can't seem to find something that work. Any help would be great.

1. Installed with composer
2. php artisan passport:install
3. put HasApiTokens in user model
4. Passport::routes(); in Auth provider
5. changed provider in config/auth.php
6. put this in web middle ware \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,

My request headers

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 17 May 2018 03:34:11 GMT
phpdebugbar-id: Xe76c4a977b813e9296e0705b5cd6bc05
Server: nginx
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.4
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 59
POST /api/chat HTTP/1.1
Host: ct.test
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 33
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://ct.test
X-XSRF-TOKEN: eyJpdiI6IkQ3K3o3SExMYVZEWnYyejJQXC9zUlpnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6Ijh6UWVtdDlzU0hIWnpqZmdmazhSc0FMWUU5MTQ1N1dXNStZVlk3amhIbjNmYmlhN3BwaEJwbTI0MU5qUjVFRUtqWWV2aW1Td3JvdDg0QTd6RWJzem9RPT0iLCJtYWMiOiJkMDE0MmU2NGY5NmY3YmIxZjAwMjI4OGM1ZDUzMTU5OTBmMjNkM2YxOTZkNzM5NTAyMzliZjc0YTgyMTUyZWQ4In0=
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4)     AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://ct.test/chat/new
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: laravel_token=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%3D%3D; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkQ3K3o3SExMYVZEWnYyejJQXC9zUlpnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6Ijh6UWVtdDlzU0hIWnpqZmdmazhSc0FMWUU5MTQ1N1dXNStZVlk3amhIbjNmYmlhN3BwaEJwbTI0MU5qUjVFRUtqWWV2aW1Td3JvdDg0QTd6RWJzem9RPT0iLCJtYWMiOiJkMDE0MmU2NGY5NmY3YmIxZjAwMjI4OGM1ZDUzMTU5OTBmMjNkM2YxOTZkNzM5NTAyMzliZjc0YTgyMTUyZWQ4In0%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IkxTM0JiQVZPekFkb3VDaFh5MTRGNWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiemxaTXZVNGlPWFFOS1o3MUx6NUgrWFc2dEFVQ1dZTUlOTWc2bUJvMXY1NVBISTZuVmFLVGlKOVNveXk0dTMyWXFjaDk1eTBlemxoa0pnWWRLWVNYR0E9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImJhNzRhM2FiYjc1Mzc4NTVlYzY3MWUwZjkwNzZlOWVhNDY3OWQ5MmNlOTc0MGM1MDg1YmViNDNjYjQ0M2Q0MDkifQ%3D%3D
```

My routes look like this

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/chat', 'ChatController@store');
});
```

Comment: You're not logged in. You aren't passing a `Bearer` token in your headers

Comment: @devk Yes I am logged in. The documentation says that everything is included in the headers.

Comment: The headers you posted do not include an `Authorization: Bearer ...` token, which is what Laravel Passport uses by default for authentication. Passing the token is done with Javascript, backend can't do it for you. Edit: I see, it can be done with cookie with the middleware you use. Sorry, my mistake here. Is the route you're tryinng to access in `routes/web.php`?

Comment: @devk This Passport middleware will attach a laravel_token cookie to your outgoing responses. This cookie contains an encrypted JWT that Passport will use to authenticate API requests from your JavaScript application. Now, you may make requests to your application's API without explicitly passing an access token:

Comment: Yes, you're right, I didn't know that. Is the route you're trying to access in `routes/web.php`?

Comment: no it is in the api route file. This is the example the docs give axios.get('/api/user')
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
    });

Comment: Then there's your problem. Move it to the `routes/web.php`, which isn't stateless and will let you do the authentication with cookie (the middleware you added affects `routes/web.php`, not `routes/api.php`).

Comment: @devk In the documentation it looks like the example route is in the api route file

Comment: It's not clear, that's for sure since it has `api` prefix. But any middleware you add to the `'web' => ...` group will only affect the `routes/web.php` routes

Comment: @devk I check and moving to the web routes and adding prefix to web route does not work

Comment: I'm 100% sure that the cookie authentication won't work in `routes/api`, which is stateless and doesn't have a use for cookies. I'm also 100% sure that putting any middleware into `web => ..` group will only affect web routes (which is why it's separated from the `api => ...` group). From here on I'm not sure I can help you since I've never implemented it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing API strategies. You quoted this:

> This Passport middleware will attach a laravel_token cookie to your outgoing responses. ...

This is only true if you're wanting to internally consume your application. Which is fine, but as pointed out in your comments you must then use the `web` middleware, and not the `auth:api` middleware.

This of course assumes that you're using `axios` to make the request and have kept the default javascript that Laravel ships with that automatically injects the `x-csrf-token` into the `axios` headers. Without that, this will not work.

Comment: Like I said above no matter where I put this route I get the same error

Comment: @JohnFreedom Show us how you add the headers to axios